# What does "it has expanded over the years" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "it" refer to in this context?

"**It** has expanded over the years, so university students, when this reform was decided, were spending a year and a half more [enrolled in school] than they were supposed to," Søren Nedergaard, an official in Denmark's Ministry of Higher Education and Science, told The Atlantic. "The conception was:This was more than enough. It didn't need to be this long."

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/denmark-free-education-creates-eternity-students-who-never-graduate-2017-11

Comment: "It" refers to the practise of switching courses to stay in (free) full-time education.

Comment: A copy editor would not normally allow a paragraph to begin with a quotation with a pronoun as its first word, since its reference is not perfectly clear.   *The practice, according to Soren So-and-So, Head of Such-and-Such, "has expanded in yadda yadda yadda..."*.